# Reset the ion-option values on (ionChange) - ionic 2

Tags: asp.net, html, typescript, ionic2

Does anyone know how to reset the "ion-option" values of "ion-select". I have two ion-select controls and i want my first ion-select(selectedPLocation) to change the values of my 2nd ion-select(selectedLocation) on ionChange. I am able to remove selected by setting null but i am not able to change the values of selectedLocation. Does anyone know how to reset the value of my ion-options ?

I'm currently using VS2015 s my IDE.

HTML:

```
<ion-list> 
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Parent Location</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPLocation" (ionChange)="loadLocation()">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let parentLocation of parentLocations; let i=index" [value]="parentLocation.Key">{{parentLocation.Id}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation">
                <ion-option id="locationID" *ngFor="let location of locations; let i=index" [value]="location.Key">{{location.Id}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

TypeScript:

```
public loadLocation() {
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait..."
});
loader.present();

this.selectedLocation = null; //Reset selected value only
this.locations = null; //Tried this but can't seem to reset the values

this.locationService.GetLocations(this.global.getApiUrl(), this.selectedSite, this.selectedPLocation).then(data => {
    loader.dismiss();
    this.locations = data;
}).catch((err) => {
    loader.dismiss();
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        subTitle: err,
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
});}
```

Comment: What do you want to change the values to? You have already set the values with the `*ngFor` but you doent state what you want them to change to based on anything ... another property of the locations array?

Comment: I forgot to post my Typescript codes to bind my data sorry about it. Anyway i did manage to resolve my own error thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own error, it is due to my Typescript codes call to my web service API (GetLocation).

**Previous TypeScript Code:**

```
public GetLocations(apiUrl, siteKey, pLocationKey) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(apiUrl + "site/" + siteKey + "/location/" + pLocationKey)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.Locations = data;     //Error Here
                resolve(this.Locations);;  //Error Here
            },
            err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

**Correct TypeScript Code:**

```
public GetLocations(apiUrl, siteKey, pLocationKey){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(apiUrl + "site/" + siteKey + "/location/" + pLocationKey)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
              resolve(data);     //Corrected
          },
          err =>{
            reject(err);
          });
    });
}
```